# Dynamic access to a PHP array

Tags: php, arrays

I tried to access with `$this->$arrDataName[$key]` on the element with the key `$key` from the array `$this->$arrDataName`. But PHP interpretes that wrong.

I tried it with `{ }` around the `$arrDataName` to `$this->{$arrDataName}[$key]`, but it doesn't work.

On php.net I found an advice, but I can't realize it.

> In order to use variable variables with arrays, you have to resolve an ambiguity problem. That is, if you write $$a[1] then the parser needs to know if you meant to use $a[1]  as a variable, or if you wanted $$a as the variable and then the [1] index from that variable. The syntax for resolving this ambiguity is: ${$a[1]} for the first case and ${$a}[1] for the second.

Perhaps anyone can help me.

Thanks!

**EDIT:**

I think it doesn't work, but I forgot to fill the array.
Finally it works. :)
This is the solution: `$this->{$arrDataName}[$key]`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your syntax is correct:

```
$this->{$varName}[$key]
```

You can also use an extra variable for this:

```
$myTempArr = $this->$arrDataName;

$myTempArr[ $key ];
```

IMHO, readability is better that way...

Comment: Thanks for the advice.
I know that way, but I search for the one line solution. ;)

Comment: I found my problem.
The specified array was empty. -.-

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php
    class Foo {
        public function __construct() {
            $this->myArray = array('FooBar');
            $arrayName = 'myArray';
            echo $this->{$arrayName}[0];
        }
    }
    new Foo;
```

This worked perfectly for me, it printed `FooBar`.

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume your array is `$this->arrDataName`. You have a `$key`, so your object would be `$this->arrDataName[$key]`.

If you want the contents of the variable which name is stored in `$this->arrDataName[$key]` you should do this:

```
<?php
    echo ${$this->arrDataName[$key]};
?>
```

Comment: Sorry, but I can't figure out, how that will help me.

Answer (score 0):

Well, as far as I know, it works. Here how I tested it:

```
<?php
class tis
{
    var $a = array('a', 'b', 'c');
    var $b = array('x', 'y', 'z');

    public function read($var)
    {
        echo $this->{$var}[1].'<br />';
    }
}

$t = new tis();
$t->read('a');
$t->read('b');
?>
```

And the output:

```
b
y
```

Check correctness of `$arrDataName`. Turn on debuging and displaying PHP erros (including notices). Maybe you're trying to read non-existing property?

Also, which PHP version you use? I assume PHP5?

Comment: ...and a comment - if possible, it's better not to use this magic. Later on, you'll have problems understanding what you wanted to do. Believe me :)

Comment: @H3llGhost: You have set `error_reporting` to `E_ALL | E_STRICT`? And `display_errors` is enabled?

Comment: Yes. The typical options for developing. ;)  
I had a board in front of my head.