# php (complex) dynamic variable name construction

Tags: php

**I've got this problem when trying to construct a variable name** 
(which should output a corresponding array element.)

I start with setting the variables for testing purposes, normally the piece variable would hold the first element of an array $piece.

```
$wordnumber = 0;
$piece[0] = "forever";
```

I later echo them right before my problem to see if they're still ok.

```
echo "$piece[0]";
echo "$wordnumber";
```

The output is ok.

```
forever0
```

But then comes the problem, as I'm trying to make a function that automatically handles every single array element, so I want it to construct the next corresponding variable every time. **However somehow it has no value** after construction.

```
$name = ${'piece[' . $wordnumber . ']'};
echo "$name";
```

outputs nothing...

I've tried a lot of different formatting, I really don't know why I'm failing so hard here.
The code isn't part of any function right now btw.

**Update:
$name = $piece[$wordnumber] solves the problem
I'm curious though why my previous formatting didn't work as expected.**

**Update: Question solved by André, the problem was that $piece[0] wasn't actually part of an array. So $piece was the actual variable. After storing an actual array $piece = array("Redish", "Yellow", "Green"); at start and using global $piece; in my function everything started working like a charm.**

Comment: possible duplicate. PHPs variable variables syntax doesn't support access by array index. read my full my answer (with solution) here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9374292/variable-name-as-variable/9374603#9374603

Comment: It seems I didn't search existing questions well enough just found this formatting $myTempArr[ $key ]; on [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3235632/dynamic-access-to-a-php-array)
So I changed it to $name = $piece[ $wordnumber ]; and now it works like a charm outputting forever.

Comment: My question remains though, why ${piece[0]} with my apparently somehow faulty construction didn't work. I'm the curious type I guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven’t tested the code, but I think your first approach didn’t work because your variable’s name is “piece”, not “piece[0]”. In other words, `${'piece'}[0]` should work, but `${'piece[0]'}` is wrong. Try add this in the very beginning of your script and PHP should display you some complaints:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set("display_errors", 1);
```

Comment: Very good André! Smart thinking! And very educational for me.
The problem was indeed in the variable not being an actual array!
I changed it to $piece = array("Red", "Yellow", "Green", "Blue", "Indigo"); and now everything works like a charm.

Comment: Thanks for your kind words. If my answer was enough for you, please set it as your accepted answer ;]

Answer (score 1):

Try just `$name = $piece[$wordnumber];` and `echo $name`
this will output `"forever"`

Comment: Yes this is correct, it also works with spaces like this $piece[ $wordnumber ] btw. I'm meanwhile searching for the reason behind my first formatting's dysfunction.

Comment: the array dereferers (`[]`) shall not be included in a string I think. Therefore ${'parts'}[$wordnumber] works.