# Accessing arrays created dynamically with php

Tags: php, arrays

During the execution all errors are saved into an array like this:

```
$this->errors[$section] = $e->getMessage();
```

The thing is that, after the execution, I have to publish all sections included the ones that experimented an error concatenated with the error. When I try to to:

```
echo $this->errors[$section];
```

this is the warning I get:

```
Warning: Illegal offset type in ....
```

The solution described at [Dynamic access to a PHP array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3235632/dynamic-access-to-a-php-array) didn't help.

Comment: You want to get all of the messages in the array? Or just a specific one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check to see if the index is valid before using it:

```
if (array_key_exists($section, $this->errors) ) { 
    echo $this->errors[$section]; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

IF you haven't set `$section`, then PHP won't know what to return.

Assuming that your sections are arrays have some sort of ID number or string:

```
$errors[$section['id']] = $e->getMessage();
...
foreach($errors as $error){
    print_r($error);
}
```

I have a feeling that your problem is in the fact that $section is no longer set to what you want in the second code block.

Comment: I didn't - I saw you removed your comment and I wouldn't want to steal rep.

Comment: There's no indication in OP's question that `$section` is an array.

Comment: I take that back. It's the `offset type` that's illegal, and therefore may be due to `$section` having been defined as an array. You may be on to something here.

Comment: I think it's that $section isn't set properly in the second portion of the code, so OP needs to have some sort of ID to reference it properly.

Comment: Yes and no; OP just needs to make sure that its value is what he *thinks* it is before trying to access the index at value `$section`.

Comment: And OP delivers! FYI the best solution when accessing a dynamically created index is to verify that the index exists first. If your variable is of the wrong type, the test will throw an error and help to debug the issue.

Comment: $section  is readed from a xml file. Your solution didn't help because not all sections are at the     $errors  array.